# Is it possible to automatically "show X more comment(s)" instead of having to click? I might break a nail

Tags: feature-request

I am new to SE (and already addicted). I try to skim all of the comments at the end of an answer section to learn as much information as possible from the brilliant minds here.

Is there a way to automatically expand the "show X more comments" below each answer section? Is there a setting somewhere and / or a script I can run to always receive all comments without the hunt and clickfest? It would be convenient to have an always expand option somewhere in the SE settings instead of a clickfest...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is. Moreover, it's probably not a desirable feature to have since comments are meant to be transient, temporary things used primarily to request clarification or suggest improvements of the real content: questions and answers. The automatic partial hiding of long comment chains is a very deliberate way of keeping the focus on the Q&A, where it belongs. In general, a large number of comments on any post is a strong sign that something has gone terribly wrong with it.

Comment: In principle it is possible for you to essentially write this feature yourself via a "user script" injected with a browser extensions like Greasemonkey, as [many people on Meta StackExchange seem to love doing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/userscript). But that's probably only worth the effort for the most diehard of SE users.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250122/165773